# Why there's difference between the output of these 2 code snippets?

Tags: asp.net

Snippet 1:

```
<% _message.InnerText = this.GetType().ToString(); %>
<h3>Page type: <span id=_message runat=server/></h3>
```

Snippet 2:

```
<h3>Page type: <span id=_message runat=server/></h3>
<% _message.InnerText = this.GetType().ToString(); %>
```

1 gives me the expected output, but 2 gives me nothing.

Why?

Comment: its because in Snippet 2, the span is ALREADY rendered thats why any changes made to that control will only take effect on the next postback, while in Snippet 1 is vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Linus said, "Read the f*** source code."
So I decompile the code and got this:

for 1.

```
// ASP.default_aspx
private void __Renderform1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
{
    __w.Write("\r\n    ");
    parameterContainer.Controls[0].RenderControl(__w);
    __w.Write("\r\n    start\r\n        <h3>Page type:");
    parameterContainer.Controls[1].RenderControl(__w);
    __w.Write("</h3>\r\n        ");
    this._message.InnerText = base.GetType().ToString();
    __w.Write("\r\n    end\r\n    ");
}
```

for 2.

```
// ASP.default_aspx
private void __Renderform1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
{
    __w.Write("\r\n    ");
    parameterContainer.Controls[0].RenderControl(__w);
    __w.Write("\r\n    start\r\n        ");
    this._message.InnerText = base.GetType().ToString();
    __w.Write("\r\n        <h3>Page type:");
    parameterContainer.Controls[1].RenderControl(__w); // Here the change has no effect.
    __w.Write("</h3>\r\n    end\r\n    ");
}
```

So, there're 2 key points:

1. The ASP.NET parser render the whole page in a from-top-to-bottom
   fashion, **literally**.
2. The confusion arise from my traditionl experience with the desktop
   application.

For Desktop apps, it's like: Code -> Memeory -> UI

For ASP.NET apps, it's like: Code -> Memory ->Ouput Buffer-> UI

In the snippet 2, the change does happen for Code -> Memory step, but it didn't get chance to propgate to the Output Buffer, and thus nothing changed on the ultimate UI.

**So the root cause is we have an extra stage before we reach the UI for ASP.NET apps.**

I hope I make myself clear.

Comment: Try to edit your post and answer it. Don't update the answer in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out in the comments it's because the span tag is already rendered and delivered to the browser before your code executes. However I believe if you set the Response.Buffer flag to true they will both behave the same. Put this line of code at the top of your page:

```
<% Response.Buffer = true; %>
```

(I'm just guessing here. I haven't tested this because the situation is one you should avoid to begin with.)

Interestingly enough I believe your demonstration is one of many great examples of why inline code is just a bad idea. It's an approach that ultimately does not mesh well with how web servers and web browsers behave.

Comment: The Responser.Buffer determines wheter to buffer the output until a complete reponse is ready. It's irrelevant to the rendnering sequence of the page controls.